# Android|Concurrent-TimeoutException

Tags: android, java.util.concurrent, timeoutexception

Getting crash due to java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException in my app reported from playstore. I tried to reproduce this but not able to do that. Below is the StackTrace from google playstore. Any suggestions/help will be appreciated?

---

**Error Log:**

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: 
>       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_shutdown (Native Method)
>       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close (OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1011)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close (SocketHttpClientConnection.java:205)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close (DefaultClientConnection.java:161)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.closeConnection
>   (AbstractConnPool.java:320)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.shutdown (ConnPoolByRoute.java:678)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.shutdown
>   (ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:256)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.finalize
>   (ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:105)
>       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize (Daemons.java:187)
>       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:170)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

Comment: Definitely it has something to do with concurrent connections to your web service. You cannot replicate this with one or two users

Comment: did you use socket in your app?

Comment: I used okhttp3 lib. is that creating this issue?